# Breezingforms - Forms not working properly when displayed inside module/article

Tags: joomla, joomla-extensions, breezingforms

I have installed Breezingforms on my joomla site yesterday and very strange thing happened. Forms are working perfectly when I display them in module in a module position. But when I try to put them in an article or other module with {loadposition ...} or {BreezingForms: form_name} they wont send data and record is not saved. Any suggestions?

Comment: any success on this issues

Answer (score 0):

You could try changing the order of the loadposition plugin and the Breezing Forms content plugin in Plugin Manager.